# The Dimensions on comparison of Google Analytics APP+WEB property is disabled

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-firebase

Last Thursday, most dimensions on comparison function of Google Analytics APP+WEB property is disabled. So we can't use comparison function.

I think it's some kind of api bug, if someone knows about this please let me know when it will be able.

[error message shows 'No data currently available for this dimenstion'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0yTTQ.png)

Answer (score 0):

Check if the Google Analytics data source contains data for the specific combination of dimensions and measures.

Comment: I think they upgraded some functions for comparison (https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/9164320?hl=en&ref_topic=9143232), but they didn't check basic comparison.

Comment: you can see the screenshot, 'country', 'language',' Region' is the auto gathering information.

Answer (score 0):

I think Google has done hotfix yesterday. So Today We can use whole dimension in comparison.